# how to make a php web application where user visit through pre register subdomainp

Tags: php, mysql, html, css, cpanel

i have make a web application where only pre register user can login and use user dashboard and logout.
for example this application run on php-mysql(cpanel)
"www.example.com/system/index.php" 
But i want 
if their is two pre register user like 1. user1(subdomain : sys1.user1.com) 2. user2(subdomain : sys2.user2.com) pre register user with their pre register subdomain and this subdomain point to "www.example.com/system/index.php".
 for both two user have different option in their dashboard some different page and also some similar option similar design same login logout page. user1 cannot access any things of user2 vice versa. under user1 and user2 their are also subuser a/c with some less option that upper user.

Comment: Do you mean that the page should be accesible only to people who have authenticated on sys1,user1.com and sys2.user2.com ?

Comment: yes that also. and login,logout,dashboard design and some option like change password and other are same but every user have some different option or page that only accessible by that user only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here is what i think you need.First `session` that are accessible from all the three domains.

Here is something for that

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.your-domain.com');
session_start();
```

Now your session data would be shared across all your subdomains. Next, and i am simplifying this step because i noticed you wrote `CPanel` you need common session path for all subdomains. That is already done because by default `session` uses file to store session data. If you scale to multiple servers, make sure your session data is stored in some database server and accessible to all of the subdomains.

Now you need to differentiate between which subdomain did the user came from. For that it is simple add a flag variable in login system to both to write the subdomain in php session. Example

```
<?php
    if (user.login($username,$password)) {
      $_SESSION["authenticated"] = True;
      $_SESSION["authSource"]    = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    }
?>
```

the method `user.login` is only for representation and not any actual method. You can change it according to your codes.

So in conclusion the first part of the code segment will share session cookies across all subdomains of your domain. and the second part will set a flag on `$_SESSION` on which subdomain did the authentication occur from.

Comment: it will work for if 1st user was "sy1.abc.com" and 2nd user was "sy2.efg.com" . At the login time it detect where the user coming frm  "sy1.abc.com"  or "sy2.efg.com" and if it is coming frm "sy1.abc.com" then send it to like "www.mydomain.com/system/abc/index.php" and if  "sy2.efg.com" then "www.mydomain.com/system/efg/index.php".

Comment: one more thing is it  possible to do "www.mydomain.com/system/index.php" is only accessible or visible if user coming through "sy2.efg.com" and "sy1.abc.com"  if i type url bar "www.mydomain.com/system/index.php" it show 500 error. and user of  "sy2.efg.com" view their browser url bar "sy2.efg.com/index.php" not "www.mydomain.com/system/efg/index.php"....

Comment: look at function `session_set_cookie_params` that can be used to share session data across domains/subdomain. So yes to answer first question, it will work for both of them

Comment: for www/mydomain.com/system/index.php you will have to write a simple condition that checks on the flag where the user is from and selectively displays the content to same